# PHP link two drop downs: Show first to users -> submit seconds value [hidden]

Tags: php, dropdown

I have a drop down with none english UrlEncoded values(%D8%B3%D9%84%D8) and as you can see, the value is not in human readable format.

```
<option value='$title_v'>" . $title . "</option>
```

at the next step I've add label:

```
<option value='$title_v' label='".urldecode ($title)."'>" . $title . "</option>
```

and it's working perfect in all browsers other than firefox (firefox didn't support label attribute)

and in next step I've decoded `$title` in option:

```
<option value='$title_v' label='".urldecode ($title)."'>" . urldecode ($title) . "</option>"
```

but decoded `$title` returns wrong answer and ajax function fail to load content.

so I've write another line for detecting firefox:

```
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (strpos($browser, 'Firefox') or strpos($browser, 'firefox') or strpos($browser, 'Mozilla') or strpos($browser, 'mozilla') !== false)
```

working fine, so if "firefox" = true :

I want to display "New Select/Option" to users which is in human readable format and users can read and select item they want to, but for submiting value, use the original encoded "Select/Oprion" which is hidden but is in sync with "New Select/Option"

can i? how?

did you know better solution?

Comment: What is the problem with using? 
`<option value='$title_v'>" . urldecode ($title) . "</option>`

Comment: Like this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/evtjah0q/3/)

Comment: `<option value='$title_v'>" . urldecode ($title) . "</option>` will return wrong string for ajax load function based on `$title` and ajax returns 'nothing were found'

Comment: nope, like this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wkfun35o/)

Comment: So, you want more than one data field per option? How about
`<option value='$title_v' data-title='$title'>" . urldecode ($title) . "</option>`

Comment: If you describe what you are trying to achieve it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and a second value field.

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e){
  alert($(this).find(':selected').val());
  alert($(this).find(':selected').data('value2'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option selected disabled>Select</option>
  <option value='text 2' data-value2="%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85">only show this field</option>
</select>
```